# Update Entity Framework 5 to 6 : ObjectStateManager, AddObject, DeleteObject, ExecuteStoreCommand not member of

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've updated my project from Entity Framework 5 to 6. Therefore all assembly references to System.Data.Entity.dll were removed and the new ones (EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer) added. Last I've added the "Code Generated Items" to my EDMX file for EF6 and compiled my project.

**My problem now is that I can't access ObjectStateManager, AddObject, DeleteObject and ExecuteStoreCommand?**

For example:

```
db.DATATABLE.AddObject(dataObject)
```

genetates the error: 'AddObject' is not a member of 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet(Of Data.CMS_IMAGES)'.

BTW: I'm using Oracle ManagedDataAccess Client.

Comment: You also moved from the older `ObjectContext` API to the more versatile `DbContext` API. I'd recommend you browse through your code base and change `AddObject` into `Add`, etc.

Comment: Thanks but is there also a solution for 'DeleteObject', 'ExecuteStoreCommand' and 'ObjectStateManager'?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I rewrote my code from ObjectContext to DbContext.

**Delete**

```
Public Sub Delete(id As Decimal)
    Dim dataObject As New DATATABLE() With {.ID= id}
    db.Entry(dataObject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

**Insert and Update**

```
Public Sub InsertOrUpdate(id As Decimal, value1 As String, value2 As String)
    Dim dataObject As New CMS_USER_TO_ROLE With {
        .ID= id,
        .VALUE1= value1,
        .VALUE2= value2
    }

    'db.DATATABLE.Add(dataObject)
    db.Entry(dataObject).State = If(userToRoleId = 0, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

**SQL Command**

Change `db.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE ...")` to `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE ...")`